# Render cell border in IE, Chrome

Tags: css, ckeditor, xhtml

Has anyone idea why cell border on this page http://www.skirent.pl/informacje/cennik.html is well rendered in FF, but not in IE and Chrome?

I used CKEditor to generate this table, and I cannot find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a border with CSS (currently it isn't).

```
#subright th{
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

I think, you can't do this in CKEditor directly.

Comment: your idea was good, but then all changes in CKEditor wasn't working. Solution came with new CKE version (3.5) where is possibility to set advanced table settings and add style or class.